# Show images in web flutter

Tags: flutter, image, server

```
Error: [object ProgressEvent]
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 327:10  createErrorWithStack
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 337:28            _throw
dart-sdk/lib/core/errors.dart 120:5                                           throwWithStackTrace
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1386:11                                          callback
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                              _microtaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                               _startMicrotaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 181:15           <fn>
```

This error doesn't open photos on the web. The server cannot open photos on the web.

Show photos on the web but don't show images on the web.